# XSLT : Modify value in one node on the basis of another element's value in another node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

i have never worked on xslt before this. i am trying to transform one xml to another completely same except i need to modify one elements value on the basis of another elements which is in another node.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
   <companyCode>002</companyCode>
   <transportation>
      <express>
         <revenue>
            <rateSourceCode>REBS</rateSourceCode>
         </revenue>
      </express>
   </transportation>
   <system>
      <control>
         <engineName>OR</engineName>
      </control>
      <activityCc>1000</activityCc>
      <transactionName>RB</transactionName>
   </system>
</root>
```

OUTPUT XML: 
i need to check the transactionName which is under System node and on the basis of that i have to modify rateSourceCode value which is under transportation > express > revenue

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thsi one is copying everything but i dont know how to modify teh one node after comparison.

Comment: What should the output XML look like? And what is the logic of the comparison?

Comment: somehow I found the solution for that one, I am gonna post that soon.